# How to pass a variable to DOM element when assigning a function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to link both functions and variables to a DOM element?

Below is an example of how this might work:

```js
function logfunc(value){
  console.log(value)
}

document.getElementById('logger1').onclick = logfunc('this is button1')

document.getElementById('logger2').onclick = logfunc('this is button2')
```

```html
<input type="button" id="logger1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" id="logger2" value="Button 2">
```

#### Expected result:

'This is Button x' on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below uses [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to do something when you click the button, and [`.value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_attr_value.asp) to get the value of the element. The [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a keyword that in this case means the button you clicked. In other words, since the button you clicked is represented by `document.getElementById('logger1')` in the DOM, you can simply use `this` to represent that.

Also I don't know if it was an actual error, or a typo, but you spelled `function` like `fucntion`. I fixed that error for you in the snippet.

And finally, you used `.onclick`. That works, and is valid code, but it isn't the best way to do it. Since I won't be going into this (this isn't the main question), you might want to go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick/6348597#6348597) to find out more.

```js
function logfunc(value) {
  console.log(value)
}

document.getElementById('logger1').addEventListener("click", function() {
  logfunc('this is ' + this.value);
});

document.getElementById('logger2').addEventListener("click", function() {
  logfunc('this is ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="logger1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" id="logger2" value="Button 2">
```

Comment: Do we have to use a value set in the DOM or can we also pass a value to the function from our javascript?

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee you can pass a value from the javascript. Just replace `this.value` with what you want to pass

Comment: Awesome thank you for your help Aniket G, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee Your welcome. And as a general rule, I saw you used `.onclick`. Don't. It works, but `.addEventListener` is better. If you want to find out more, look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick/6348597#6348597

Comment: I see. Thank you Aniket, I did not know about the differences.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to give a callback/listener function data

One would be to use a closure. Change `logfunc` to return a function the "closes" over `value`.

see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```js
function logfunc(value){
  return function() {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

document.getElementById('logger1').onclick = logfunc('this is button1')

document.getElementById('logger2').onclick = logfunc('this is button2')
```

```html
<input type="button" id="logger1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" id="logger2" value="Button 2">
```

Otherwise you can put data in the DOM in various ways. DOM data is generally limited to strings, variables are not.

```js
function logfunc(value){
  return function() {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

document.getElementById('logger1').onclick = logfunc({name: 'Joe', age: 12})

document.getElementById('logger2').onclick = logfunc({name: 'Bob', age: 14})
```

```html
<input type="button" id="logger1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" id="logger2" value="Button 2">
```

Otherwise if you want to put data in the DOM itself then you're mostly limited to strings. You can reference the `value` attribute in your code

```js
function logfunc(e){
  console.log(e.target.value);
}

document.getElementById('logger1').onclick = logfunc;

document.getElementById('logger2').onclick = logfunc;
```

```html
<input type="button" id="logger1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" id="logger2" value="Button 2">
```

But `value` is not available on all DOM elements.

You can instead use [dataset attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to store arbitrary data on elements

```js
// select all elements that have a "data-name" attribute
document.querySelectorAll('*[data-name]').forEach((elem) => {

  // on each element add a click handler (better than using onclick!)
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    // access the dataset attributes
    console.log(elem.dataset.name, elem.dataset.major);
  });
});
```

```css
div[data-name] { 
   background: pink;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0.25em;
   padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div data-name="Bill" data-major="dance">Button 1</div>
<div data-name="Mary" data-major="science">Button 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that is bind to an element will has a scope that "this" is refering to the element self. so you can get the value of the input by "this.value"

```js
function logfunc(){
  console.log('this is ' + this.value);
}

document.getElementById('logger1').onclick = logfunc

document.getElementById('logger2').onclick = logfunc
```

```html
<input type="button" id="logger1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" id="logger2" value="Button 2">
```

Comment: Great answer. However, on Stack Overflow, we usually want you to give some kind of explanation. Not just working code

Comment: Ok, the function that is bind to an element will has a scope that "this"  is refering to the element self. so you can get the value of the input by "this.value"

Comment: Put that explanation inside the answer. Most people just read the answer - not the comments.